# Change zoom on a background image after background-size: cover

Tags: css, image, background, background-size

I have a background image as a header. When the screen size is 800 pixels or less the letters of the background image don't fit anymore. I need to zoom out a bit so that the letters will fit on the screen. Is there a way to control the zoom of a background image?

(Source: http://steampunk-jewelry.nl/. "Steampunk Jewelry" doesn't fit on the screen when it's 800 pixels or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `transform: scaleY` for block with background and then `transform: scaleY` with opposite value for its content.

In current case you can set `transform: scaleY(0.9)` for `.single-slide` and `transform: scaleY(1.1111)` (`1.1111 ≈ 1 / 0.9`) for its direct child.